# Need explanation on recursive and generator example

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, generator, yield

I have this recursive function which is used to generate all possible up and lower cases to any string value you pass it to it.

Here is the code sample and the output:

```
def test (name):

    if not name:
        yield ""

    else:
        first=name[:1]

        for sub in test(name[1:]):

            yield first.lower()+sub
            yield first.upper()+sub
            #print (first)

for x in test("abc"):
    print (x)
```

the output will be like this :

```
abc
Abc
aBc
ABc
abC
AbC
aBC
ABC
```

and if I add print function under the two yield functions:

```
print(first)
```

the out put will be like this :

```
abc
Abc
a
aBc
ABc
a
b
abC
AbC
a
aBC
ABC
a
b
c
```

I just want a clear explanation for each step and what is happening and why I got these value each time and how does it work, because recursive and generators together made me lost here.

Comment: the fact that you are dealing with a generator makes no difference here. It would be exactly the same if instead of `yield` you had `return` with a bit of re-organising. Also the generator should not be hard to understand if you feel comfortable with _slicing_. As a final remark, printing `first` does not get you far in understanding. Try printing the **argument** that goes in the function each time it is called.

Comment: thank you for your reply .... 
yes i already tried that and i got exactly what was supposed to be in my mind 
argument passed "abc"
argument passed "bc"
argument passed "c"
argument passed ""
, but the question is if you understand generation and recursion .. just give me the trace of this program .. i just want to learn how this works step by step ...

why it prints 
abc , Abc then aBC ... from the code the next call "first should equal "b"!!

there is something about recursion i miss here !!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you stuck in producing your own trace?  You've shown that you know how to use **print** statements.  I assume that you also know how to search other examples of recursion traces; StackOverflow has many.

To get you started, here's your code with a couple more **print** statements.

```
def test (name):
    print ("ENTER test, name=", name)

    if not name:
        yield ""

    else:
        first=name[:1]

        for sub in test(name[1:]):
            print ("  LOOP\tname", name, "\tfirst", first, "\tsub", sub)

            yield first.lower()+sub
            yield first.upper()+sub
            #print (first)

for x in test("abc"):
    print ("YIELDED:", x)
```

Output:

```
ENTER test, name= abc
ENTER test, name= bc
ENTER test, name= c
ENTER test, name= 
  LOOP  name c  first c     sub 
  LOOP  name bc     first b     sub c
  LOOP  name abc    first a     sub bc
YIELDED: abc
YIELDED: Abc
  LOOP  name abc    first a     sub Bc
YIELDED: aBc
YIELDED: ABc
  LOOP  name bc     first b     sub C
  LOOP  name abc    first a     sub bC
YIELDED: abC
YIELDED: AbC
  LOOP  name abc    first a     sub BC
YIELDED: aBC
YIELDED: ABC
```

Does this get you moving in a useful direction?

Answer (score 0):

thanks .... 
yesterday i just took a paper ,a pen and i trace this function from stack view and i understand it ...

it's recursive so the function will call itself from the second letter to the end of whole string each time till the the function "test" called with "" value ...

then i have to apply the for loop each time from the last to the first ... 
the last will have variables like this : first ="c" , sub=""

```
for each sub :
    first.lower+sub >> c 
    first.upper+sub>>  C
```

then back to the previous call will take the last result 
so for each "c" and for each "C" will apply

```
first.lower()+sub > bc bC 
first.upper()+sub > bC BC
```

then back to the first call with last result
right now we have sub = bc,Bc,bC,BC
and first ='a'

```
 for each sub :

first.lower+sub
first.upper+sub

abc
Abc
aBc
ABc
abC
AbC 
aBC
ABC
```